# doxygen - how to "using" within subclass?

Tags: c++, subclass, doxygen, using

If I have a subclass which reintroduces members of the base class with "using", how do I get doxygen to create entries / docs for these members?

```
class Foo {
protected:
  virtual void hello();
};

class Bar : protected Foo {
public:
  /**
   * \brief Reintroduced
   * This documentation will not show up :-(
   */
  using Foo::hello;
};
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Which settings do you have in your doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile)  that differ from the standard settings?

Comment: DoxyGen V1.8.7, only project name, description and optimize for C have been modified and 2 names added to exclude symbols.

Comment: Please upgrade to the current version 1.8.14 as far as I can see the information is present here.

Comment: Thanks, I've just build V1.8.15 from github and it all works now. Was not aware of the repo version being so out-dated :)

Comment: With repo I assume that you mean the software repo of you OS distribution.